# Register type with factory delegate

Tags: c#, .net, autofac

Is there a way in Autofac to register a type with a factory delegate that gets called when that type is requested?
Something like this:

```
builder.RegisterType<MyType>().AsSelf()
       .WithFactory((IMyService s, ISomeDependency d) =>
                    {
                        var p1 = s.DoSomething();
                        var p2 = d.DoSomething(p1, true);
                        return new MyType(p1, p2);
                    });
```

Comment: You want Autofac to call that delegate and inject the `IMyService` and `ISomeDependency` in that call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably not quite you expect, but does do the trick:

```
builder.Register<MyType>(container =>
{
    var s = container.Resolve<IMyService>();  
    var d = container.Resolve<ISomeDependency>();

    var p1 = s.DoSomething();
    var p2 = d.DoSomething(p1, true);
    return new MyType(p1, p2);
});
```

Or if you want to use automatic (constructor) injection, you can create a `MyType` subclass (inside the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot.aspx)), that takes the two dependencies. This type can easily be registered:

```
builder.RegisterType<AutofacMyType().As<MyType>();

// Define inside Composition Root
private sealed class AutofacMyType : MyType
{
    public AutofacMyType(IMyService s, ISomeDependency d)
        : this(s.DoSomething(), d) { }

    private AutofacMyType(Something p1, ISomeDependency d)
        : base(p1, d.DoSomething(p1, true)) { }
}
```

Comment: That's what I am using right now and I don't like it, because I have to resolve the dependencies myself...

Comment: The second one is a good idea, but it will only work, if the logic to create the instance is rather simple.

Comment: I personally see no problem in calling `container.Resolve` as long as that code is inside the Composition Root (and not in the application), but if you want to use automatic (constructor) injection, you can create a `MyType` subclass (inside the Composition Root), that takes the two dependencies; see my update.

Comment: Your comment crossed mine. I agree, with you that this only works when the logic is simple, but wiring up should of course be as simple as possible. It's impossible for me to tell, but isn't there a problem with your design?

Comment: I guess you are right. Thanks for your answer, it made me rethink, why I don't like the call to `Resolve`. ("Because it's not in the composition root", but you are right - it actually IS in the composition root, so I guess it's ok)

Comment: Injecting dependencies in a delegate is an interesting idea though. There was a similar question about Castle Windsor a few days back: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131047/is-there-a-simple-way-to-register-static-closures-with-castle-windsor. There are however problems with doing that. Mark Seemann's answer is very interesting.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. Yes, Marks answers always are interesting!